# How can I manage loopback apps?

Tags: node.js, loopback

I'm a new loopback developer. My job now is to create microservices by loopback.

But I don't know what tool to manage, analyze, load balancing, ... for a production environment. I know strongloob-pm can do this, but it will be soon deprecated.

So can anyone give me some information about those tools? And I prefer free tools.

Thanks guys.